# Downloading a zip file from Bing Ads API with node.js - not even gettng a statusCode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, bing-api

The Bing Ads API v8 background: With my node.js script, I'm using the SubmitGenerateReport operation to create a Campaign PerformanceReportRequest, which returns an ID that I then use to call PollGenerateReport, which returns a long URL, ex:

https://download.api.bingads.microsoft.com/ReportDownloadAdCenterAPIDownload.aspx?q=M3poINDSV[ about 200 characters removed ]05GUMsXBg%3d

GETing that URL with a browser or wget immediately returns the file I need.

If I use a browser, I also get a friendly file name such as "CampaignPerformanceReport_08_29_2013_11_06_54.zip" ... with wget I am specifying -O and assigning a file name.

Ideally I want to stream the zip file into adm-zip and unzip it on the fly, or something like that.

However, I am unable to even get response.statusCode property from the URL with either node https nor node-request.

I've searched and seen discussion where there are some known ECONNRESET issues with node, but they don't seem to apply to my situation from what I can tell.

My current thought is that either:

1. Something about the long URL to .zip file response isn't getting picked up by node - I've tried to detect a redirect but like I mentioned, I'm not even getting a statusCode
2. Maybe there is a header I need to specify for Bing Ads API to be happy?

Here's some code with associated errors:

Using node HTTPS:

```
https.get(file_url, function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
  console.log("headers.location: " + res.headers.location);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

After about 35 seconds, returns the error:

```
Got error: read ECONNRESET
```

and without the .on error, more verbosely:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:556:19)
```

Using node-request:

```
request(file_url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!response.statusCode == 200) {
       console.log(response.statusCode)
    }
});
```

After about 35 seconds, returns the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
    at Request._callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\testzipstream.js:35:18)
    at self.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\request\index.js:148:
22)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at ClientRequest.self.clientErrorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modul
es\request\index.js:257:10)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at CleartextStream.socketErrorListener (http.js:1528:9)
    at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.onerror (tls.js:1424:17)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at net.js:441:14
```

What am I missing and/or what else should I be investigating? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure is related with http headers. I had once a similar problem, I was able to download a file using wget or curl, but node gave me a `500` error response.

It turns out that wget and curl send `Accept: */*` and node didn't by default. (And for some reason the server didn't like that this header was missing)

To figure it that out, I used [ngrep](http://ngrep.sourceforge.net/) to sniff the headers.

So, try that, sniff the petition with wget and then sniff it with node.

Then compare the headers. Replace the headers node send to be the same as wget and that's it.

Comment: Thanks - ngrep let me see headers, but what it ultimately showed me was that my requests to Bing via node http get/node request are going into a black hole even when I carefully recreate the headers. Nothing comes back. I am doing an exec wget to make it work. At some point in the near future I'll write all this up against the Bing sandbox so anyone can try to recreate.

Answer (score 0):

Bing Ads Api uses SSLv3, Node uses SSLv1 by default, if you specify in the https globalAgent to use SSLv3 it will work.

```
https.globalAgent.options.secureProtocol='SSLv3_method';
```